# Probability using Chebyshev equation

Tags: probability-theory

A dice is rolled until the result is 6 and this is repeated n times. Sn represents the total amount of times the dice is being rolled (in order to get 6 total of n times). Find the probability for -0.1 < Sn/n - 6 < 0.1 where n=100 and n=10000.

I am not able to think of a way to find EX and DX, after that, I have the basic idea how the probability is found. So a push to a direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the technical information asked for in the OP.

Let $W_1$ be the waiting time (number of tosses) until the first $6$, $W_2$ the waiting time between the first $6$ and the second, and so on up to $W_n$. The $W_i$ are independent random variables with **geometric** distribution. We have $E(W_i)=\frac{1}{1/6}=6$ and $\text{Var}(W_i)=\frac{1-\frac{1}{6}}{(1/6)^2}=30$. So $\sum W_i$ has mean $6n$ and variance $30n$.

But $\sum W_i=S_n$. Thus $\frac{S_n}{n}$ has mean $6$ and variance $\frac{30}{n}$.